# Remove empty lines and timestamp from subtitle file in Notepad++

Tags: timestamp, notepad++, subtitle

i want remove empty lines and timestamp from subtitle file in Notepad++

I know this question has already been asked and the answer is this code:
^[\d\s\n].*\n

But if at the beginning of the text is a number, That line is also deleted.

For example, on the following lines:

1- We've already seen better ways to organise our code

2- we've seen ways to deal with files,

```html
1
00:00:01.876 --> 00:00:02.709
<v Instructor>We can go back now</v>

2
00:00:02.709 --> 00:00:05.042
to our web server checklist.

3
00:00:06.410 --> 00:00:08.722
1- We've already seen better ways to organise our code

4
00:00:08.722 --> 00:00:11.545
into reusable pieces with modules,

5
00:00:11.545 --> 00:00:13.315
2- we've seen ways to deal with files,

6
00:00:13.315 --> 00:00:15.940
both synchronous and asynchronous,

7
00:00:15.940 --> 00:00:16.773
and buffers,

8
00:00:16.773 --> 00:00:18.325
both the built-in Node one

9
00:00:18.325 --> 00:00:20.380
and the ES6 buffers,

10
00:00:20.380 --> 00:00:22.485
and we've seen a way to deal with work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\R?(\d+)\R\d\d:\d\d.+\R`
- Replace with: `$1 -`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
\R          # any kind of linebreak
\d\d:\d\d   # 2 digit, colon, 2digit
.+          # 1 ormore any character but newline
\R          # any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1  # content of group 1, digits
 -  # space, dash, space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1 - <v Instructor>We can go back now</v>
2 - to our web server checklist.
3 - 1- We've already seen better ways to organise our code
4 - into reusable pieces with modules,
5 - 2- we've seen ways to deal with files,
6 - both synchronous and asynchronous,
7 - and buffers,
8 - both the built-in Node one
9 - and the ES6 buffers,
10 - and we've seen a way to deal with work
```